# regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate a texbox to allow numbers and letter(s) but not letters alone only e.g. 13492M

I am using C# regular expressions.

Comment: "to allow numbers and letter(s) but not letters" ?? Did you mean not letters alone?

Comment: I guess , it must be alphanumeric ?

Comment: @frenchie I think he means "to allow numbers and letter(s) but not _only_ letters"

Comment: Numbers and letters in any combination, or a sequence of numbers followed by one or more letters per your example? At any rate, look up the | (alternative) operator in regexes.

Comment: Your problem is underspecified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^[A-Za-z]*\d[A-Za-z\d]*$` should do it. (Possibly some letters, then a digit, then any more letters or digits.)

(Edited to add start/end matches.)

Comment: I'd take out the `\d` in the first `[]`. Depending on how the regex engine works, that might improve performance.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Cheers, that should work. Took me a minute to get my head around it.

Comment: @Goran Well, the question is still open to interpretation... but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

**Details :**

- Start. `^`
- Zero or more mixed alphanumerical. `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`
- One or more numerical. `[0-9]+`
- Zero or more mixed alphanumerical. `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`
- End. `$`

Comment: No, it accepts letters and numbers mixed string or numbers only sting

Comment: A letter only string is a special case of a mixed letter-number string, and will be matched by `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: The `|^[0-9]+$` part is completely useless now. And your code looks like it might suffer from performance issues, at least it's non trivial to optimize this for a regex engine. Compare it with Rawling's code.

Comment: I'm not saying that your code is wrong, only that it might be slow for some inputs, compared with Rawlings updated code.

Comment: So, let's wait for the optimized one :)

Answer (score 0):

use maskedTextBox, it use a property "mask" to validate with the Expression that you want. So you only add the RegEx to your maskedTextBox and you don't have to validate everytime in your code (it will check against your RegEx automatically)

Answer (score 0):

This Regex should work fine:

```
^[A-Za-z]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*$
```

This regex will allow numbers or letters+numbers.  Just letters will fail.

Comment: Shouldn't you add start and end specifiers?

Comment: This won't allow a value that _starts_ with a letter... but that may well be what Karl wants, it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: @Rawling Yes it _will_ allow a value that starts with a letter.

Comment: And that looks like what he wanted from his comments. Good job :)

Comment: Ack no, totally misread that. It will allow a value that starts with a letter, but only by virtue of allowing a value that starts with _anything_.

Comment: Agreed, this will make a partial match in case of _1. So _1 will be validated.

Comment: I don't think anyone expects regexes to be pretty :)

Comment: Now it's looking much more similar to Rawling, nice work.  +1

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the question it's still wrong. It doesn't match `A1B2`. But who knows what the OP wants.

Comment: Well, at least the OP has two problems now :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 ([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+ | [a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

(Numbers first and then  alphabets   OR   Alphabets first then numbers) atleast once or more  then   both alphabets and numbers which is optional

Comment: thanks for all your replies - joshuams answer seems to have done the trick, i'll confirm and mark as answered, thanks again